# Captionless wxPython Window Hides Taskbar

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, taskbar

This code:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~wx.CAPTION)
frame.Maximize()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Produce a frame covering the whole screen, including my taskbar. Is there a way to make it only take up the screen not taken by the taskbar?

- OS: Windows XP
- Python: 2.7.3
- WxPython: 2.9.3.1

Comment: I think you could do it by leaving the window with a caption, but making the caption bar and border zero width. This would be tricky even with direct Windows API calls, not sure how to do it in wx.

Comment: @MarkRansom, can you point me to how to do in the Windows API? I'm already using some C++ in an extension module in this project, so I might be able to make that work.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not entirely sure - it would involve some experimentation on my part. I might start with WM_NCCALCSIZE, or WM_NCHITTEST.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, I would say no, you can't do it with the Maximize method. You could probably fake it by getting the screen size and setting the frame's seize to that minus the space for the taskbar. You may have to find a way to get the taskbar's position as some people don't leave it on the bottom.

Comment: +1 for "...some people don't leave it on the bottom".  I'm one of those people.

Comment: I've known at least one person who's put it on the left and another who loves it at the top.

Comment: Its even more important to worry about placement in my case, since the tablets my app runs on may have the onscreen keyboard in place as well. I was hoping that there was a way to just make windows deal with it.

Comment: You should ask on the wxPython mailing list. The main devs for wxPython are on there. They'll know if there is a way. I don't think there is, but Robin will know for sure (or he'll know who will)

Answer (score 1):

Get the working area position and size without taskbar:

```
c_x, c_y, c_w, c_h = wx.ClientDisplayRect()
```

Set pos and size:

```
frame = wx.Frame(None, pos=(c_x, c_y), size=(c_w, c_h),
                      style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~wx.CAPTION & ~wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to place a follow-up solution here, since the above question appears still valid and the problem arises in C++ as well.

A possible and rather general solution is to apply the **default** frame style **before maximizing**, then revert to your **custom** (captionless) style afterwards.

The successfully tested C++ version reads:

```
frame->SetWindowStyle(wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE);
frame->Maximize(true);
frame->SetWindowStyle(wxRESIZE_BORDER);
```

Under Windows 10, this results in the caption bar briefly flashing, but the effect appears minor.

Answer (score 0):

For future people looking. Trying using ShowFullScreen(True)

I'm new to wx but try using self.ShowFullScreen(True) or frame.ShowFullScreen(True)

Comment: In my case, I wanted to taskbar to remain unhidden. I think you'll lose that with fullscreen.